# Magento Manage Stock Wont Turn Off?

Tags: magento, inventory

I am having issues with magento configurable products. I am not able to add products to basket the because it is "out of stock". I have done all the checks, made sure the simple products have stock and made sure the configurable products are in stock, but with no luck.

I have now tried to turn off the inventory system all together in

`System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Manage Stock -> No.`

However when i click save it takes a minute to load then is set back to yes again automatically.

Anyone else have this issue previously?

Any other way to turn off the stock control?

Comment: Enable Logs in Administration, and take a look at exception.log file under _ROOT_FOLDER_/var/log/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps to find out the problem:

- enable log through admin panel ==> it will generate var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log, then you can check if there is any problem in log files
- enable error log in index.php: uncomment this line  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
- check other modules in app/code/local, maybe there is a conflict between the modules. You can even turn off all the local module and check again (app/etc/local.xml)